# Will running CSF & Bastille cause any conflicts?

Tags: csf

I'm taking my first steps into the world of un-managed servers, and have confused myself whilst reading through the 101 tutorials on server hardening that Google spews out!

The most recent advice I have been given is to install both CSF and Bastille on my server (used to serve a consumer-facing ecommerce site and act as the business' email server), but my understanding was that both of these tools were an abstraction layer above netfilter / iptables. Will installing both packages cause any conflicts, or do they play well together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bastille deals with the configuration of the server itself. It helps you harden services/operating system.  It doesn't actually touch the firewall, so it should have no conflicts with CSF.